# Sending push notification to javascript clients

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a Chrome plugin that connects to an Azure Mobile Service. 
The plugin sends messages to the service that forwards to a specific mobile device. 
The mobile device sends back an answer to the service.

How can I retrieve the answer from the chrome plug-in (or be notified the answer is ready without any proprietary 3rd party service like Pusher) in an efficient way? Is there a way to send two responses from the azure mobile service?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Chrome plugins but from your Mobile Service, you can perform a separate HTTP request using the request module prior to performing the response.  I'm not sure what Chrome exposes as an endpoint, so if you can explain that, I can let you know if there is a different option potentially.